# HTMLElement is not added to the DOM. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, dom

I have the separate template file (html). I need to load this generated HTML object to the main page several times, so I do the next thing:

```
const path = "/templates/news.tpl.html";
const template = await Dbc.Dom.loadTemplate({ 
    id  : "news-block", 
    path: path 
});

document.body.appendChild(template);
document.body.appendChild(template);
```

First, the function fetches the content from the file and add it to the current DOM. As the return value, it returns the added `HTMLElement` object.

I try to add this object again after that, then I'm using the standard way, via the `document.body.appendChild()` function, but I can see only the single template object in the current DOM.

Comment: So _one_ `HTMLElement` _is_ being added, right? Then everything works as expected. You can’t append the same object twice and expect it to be duplicated. If you want two elements, you need to create a second one. Appending only adds a new object to the DOM if it wasn’t in the DOM before. Appending it again just changes its position in the DOM, if at all.

Comment: How should I create another object, is there function to clone created template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append child just replaces your object , if u try few times your object will apear in a last place.
You should use cloneNode

sort of this :

```
    document.body.appendChild(template);
document.body.appendChild(template.cloneNode(true));
```